# How to multiprocessing / parallelizing the code in for loop

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I'm new to python but I made a program that takes a long time to compute and only uses 12% of my CPU. I figure if it used all of my CPUs it would finish quicker - especially in a for lopp. I checked through python tutorials and docs but I'm now thoroughly confused.

I have a simple code that goes like this in datacube.py:

```
def datacube(x,y,z):
    xt = x * y * z
    return xt
```

In my main program:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import datacube

x_range = np.arange(1,50,5)
y_range = np.arange(2,200,1)
z_range = np.arange(3,300,3)

x = y = 5

dump = []
data3 = [mp.Process(target=datacube.datacube, args=(x,y,z)) for z in z_range]
dump.append(data3)
```

All I want is to basically (x_range) * (y_range) * (z_range) because my program is in nested for loops. I've tried everything I know and it doesnt work.

I don't know if map, Process, or pool or other is better. I just want to get it started. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this gives you what you need.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

x_range = np.arange(1,50,5)
y_range = np.arange(2,200,1)
z_range = np.arange(3,300,3)
list(np.prod(x) for x in product(x_range,y_range,z_range))
```

Comment: what happens if the function is more like
def datacube(x,y,z):
    xt = do something with x,y,z, not necessaryily x*y*z
    return xt

Comment: I would go ahead and accept this one as the answer to this question, then post a new question in a more generalized way so it will have a chance to be answered.